# Possible deallocation of UIKit object on the non-main queue

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, automatic-ref-counting

I've faced several times in public APIs the following code style:

```
@interface UITextField (SomeFunctionalitySupport)

- (void) someMethod {
    @weakify(self)
    dispatch_async(someConcurrentQueue, ^{
        @strongify(self)
        self.text = @"Some text"
    })
}

@end
```

Given that UITextField is UIKit object it should be deallocated on the main queue. As I understand, weakify/strongify macros are just a neat way to not declare `__weak` and `__strong` local variables manually and perform conditional check on the strong one.

But `__strong` increments reference counting, right? So, until the block completes we'll have one more strong reference. And block runs on the non-main queue. What if during execution of the block the strong reference became the last one? Logically, `self`'d be deallocated upon completion of the block. But this wouldn't happen on the main queue which could cause significant problems.

Was API creators wrong or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` will not be deallocated while the block is running, because it holds a strong reference on it.

It will be deallocated after the block execution finished, because in your case it is the last strong reference. Who should care about this, since no one else has a strong reference on it?